# Rails app with two kinds of login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, postgresql, api, omniauth

I have created a rails app with my own login system, and now I would like the user to be able to login with the facebook API (omniauth) aswell.
So how do I implement this, so my users will be able to create or login with my version and be able to login with facebook?

Can they work on the same database or do I need two separate?

Any guides you can recommend?

Comment: Have you tried to use `devise`? It will save you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in this Railscast: [#241 Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth).